# Having trouble with this simple SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables, A and B.

Both have the exact same columns.

I need to select all the items in TableA that **ARE NOT** in TableB.

This is intersection, right? How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming TableA and TableB have a primary key of name id.

```
select TableA.* 
  from TableA 
left outer join TableB on TableB.id = TableA.id
where TableB.id is null;
```

This will find all entries where table b does not have an instance of table a's id.

Comment: I get an error using TableA.*, I'm SQL Server Express 2008. What can I do?

Comment: You could enumerate the columns you want.  For example select TableA.id, TableA.otherColumn, etc.

Comment: Fixed it using this: 
select * from ProductoA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductoB 
on ProductoB.Descripcion = ProductoA.Descripcion
where ProductoB.Descripcion is null;

Comment: You're making the assumption here that all products have a unique description.  Note that if you have two products in TableB that have the same description or the description in TableA matches a description in TableB for which the rest of the data does not match you will select incorrect data.

Comment: In SQL Server, NOT IN / NOT EXISTS are better than LEFT JOIN, since its optimizer can't discern an ANTI JOIN in a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL. It will always return all NULLS first and filter them out.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the EXISTS clause

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE NOT Exists
(
SELECT Column1 FROM TableB 
WHERE TableA.Column1 = Table2.Column1 
AND TableA.Column2 = Table2.Column2 
....
)
```

Replace .... with the rest of the columns in the two tables.

Comment: This is the better answer.  In SQL Server, NOT IN / NOT EXISTS are better than LEFT JOIN, since its optimizer can't discern an ANTI JOIN in a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL. It will always return all NULLS first and filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

You have your terminology wrong.  The [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) would be the rows that are in both Table A and Table B.  What you are actually looking for is the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of A and B.  To get a relative complement you want to do an [antijoin](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/25837-Semi-join-Anti-join.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TableB.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really informative stuff! One question though, you antijoin statement is based on the PrimaryKeys of the tables correct? What I mean is, they automatically use the PrimaryKeys to do their stuff, right?

Comment: No -- it's comparing all of the columns.  It will only filter out complete rows that exist in Table A that are also in Table B.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM TableB
```

Answer (score 1):

or NOT IN

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.Id NOT IN (SELECT TableB.Id FROM TableB)
```