# SQL Selecting rows that are in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I select rows that exist is two tables. The intersection I guess? Any help?

ProductosA and ProductosB, they're both tables with the exact same number and type of columns.

How can I select the things that are inside of both using a single select statement?

Comment: do you want to combine rows (with similar shape) from 2 tables OR form the intersection of rows that have to match in both tables?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out from your other question, take the time to understand the answers people give you :-/        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430515/having-trouble-with-this-simple-sql-select-statement

Comment: The latter, Mitch. thanks for helping out. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from ProductosA
intersect
select * from ProductosB
;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.column1, a.column2
from productosA a
join
productosB b
on
a.id = b.id
```

that will give you what you want

Answer (score 1):

If there is a primary/composite key join the two tables where the keys match, if there is no primary key, join them using where "and"ing match for each column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  ProductosATable.* 
FROM
  ProductosATable 
  INNER JOIN ProductosBTable 
    ON ProductosATable.NAME = ProductosBTable.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by specifying more than one table in your FROM clause you will get rows that exist in more than one table. Whether you get their entire rows, or just part of them, depends on how many of the columns you specify in the SELECT clause.